# Angular JS & SSO & Rest API - Angular intercepting response

Tags: angularjs, rest, single-sign-on

I have a scenario where an external application, SSOs and calls a rest api on an application running on the tomcat server. The rest api does some authentication and on succesfull authentication, the rest api "send redirects" the response to our angular JS login ui application. (going to call as login-ui).

So with this "send redirect" request that comes into the login-ui, my login-ui (angular js) interceptor is not intercepting the response. I can see that there is request headers and response headers (which has the auth token in it). But since the interceptor is not intercepting the response, I am not able to retrieve the headers.

Is there a way to retrieve the header information from the response of a Send Redirect request in angular js?

Edit:
Interceptor Code:

```
var StateInterceptor = function($injector,$q) {
var _ = require('lodash');
console.log("inside interceptor state");    
var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

return { 
     'request': function(request) {
        console.log('request', request);            
    },
    // Response with errors interception
    'responseError': function(rejection) {
        console.log('responseError args', arguments);
        console.log(rejection.status);
    },

    response: function(response) {  
        console.log(response.status);                     
        var accessToken=response.headers('site_tok');
        console.log(accessToken);

        if(response.config.nointercept)
        {
            return $q.when(response);
        }
        else
```

thanks

Comment: This usually would be done through the interceptor. Could you post your interceptor code?

Comment: Interceptor code:                                                                           var  StateInterceptor = function($injector,$q){
 console.log("inside interceptor state");    
 var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');       
    return { 
         'request': function(request){
            console.log('request', request);            
        },
        'responseError': function(rejection){
            console.log('responseError args', arguments);          
        },        
        response: function(response) {  
            console.log(response.status); }